# Can a background process launch a foreground process in the same shell?

Tags: shell, unix, process, xterm

In a system:

1. A foreground process -- let's call this process `Main()` -- running in an xterm launches a background process `Monitor()`
2. Via a database, it is possible for `Monitor()` to detect a remote interrupt and kill `Main()`
3. At a later point, the database can instruct `Monitor()` to relaunch `Main()` with different parameters

The constraints are:

1. `Main()` must always run in the foreground, and,
2. Launching a new xterm to launch `Main()` is not allowed

The question, then, is: **Can a background process launch a new foreground process in the same xterm/shell?**

TCSH is preferred, but Bash is also acceptable.

Comment: To the extent I understand what you're trying to do, I don't think it is feasible for the process in the background to launch a process using the xterm that the shell running in the xterm knows about.  You might be able to run a process using the xterm that the shell does not know about, but then you run into coordination problems — both the shell and the process are trying to read the terminal and who knows which will get which bytes of whetever is typed in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jonathan. After checking with local UNIX experts, the consensus is as you mention: there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonathan mentioned (and as I have verified independently), there is no way to do this without having a separate watcher process/daemon running in the background.